# Removing the last comma from a json file with python

Tags: python, json, csv

I am converting a csv to a json and formatting but I cannot get the len, next, or slicing methods to work. So I am at a loss on how I would get it do not add the last comma.

Looks something like this:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)
jsonfile.write("[")
for row in reader:
    sum += 1
    json.dump(row, jsonfile)
    if sum == len(reader):
        jsonfile.write(",")
        jsonfile.write("\n")
    else:
        jsonfile.write("\n")
jsonfile.write("]")
```

Comment: What is `jsonfile`? It's not [this PyPI package](https://pypi.org/project/jsonfile/).

Comment: It might be better to do `json.dump(list(reader))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to deal with terminating each row your writing nor preventing a final comma, rather use json.dumps on a list comprehension of each row of the csv.DictReader and it will all be handled:

```
import csv  
import json  

with open( '/path/to/filename.csv', 'r' ) as csvfile: 
    reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile, fieldnames = ("fn_a","fn_b","fn_c"))  
    jsonfile = json.dumps( [ row for row in reader ] )  

with open('output.json', 'w') as f: 
    f.write(jsonfile)
```

Comment: I like it. Just missing the part where you write to the `open(,'wt')`ed `jsonfile` :)

Comment: @FZs Description provided.

Comment: Do not use the name `json` to dump the string. You just lost your reference to the module.